# How to ignore backslashes appearing in the properties file for characters like : and =

Tags: java, properties, backslash

```
private static void createPropertiesFile() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    OutputStream output = null;

    try {

        output = new FileOutputStream(
                "c://properties//xyz.properties");

        // set the properties value
        prop.setProperty("URL", hostName);

        prop.store(output, null);

    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Sample data in properties file looks as below.

```
#Tue Oct 06 15:26:55 IST 2015
URL=jdbc\:sqlserver\://abc.xyz.net
```

My understand is that anything before first "=" is treated as key and anything after first "=" as treated as value. In the process, when characters like : and = are encountered,they are escaped with backslash, '\'.

Can anyone please help me on how to remove or restrict '\' from appearing in first place in properties file when encountered with : and =

Comment: Why? `Properties` should be used to easily write and read from the filesystem. If you want use the output file for something else, don't use `Properties`.

Comment: I need to use the key(i.e, URL) in this case xyz.properties, but is there a way how to handle this with properties because my requirement is to go with the properties file.

Comment: What do you mean by use? You want a second program (not in Java) to read the file and use the key-value-pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.  Properties files will treat = and : as key/value delimiters.

To make it explicit as to which part is the key and which is the value the '=' and ':' characters, if included in either part, must be escaped.

Consider the following:

```
Key: somepassword
Value: Xj993a==
```

Your properties file will look like:

```
somepassword=Xj993a==
```

Unfortunately, where is the key and where is the value? The key could be:

- somepassword with value Xj993a==
- somepassword=Xj993a with value =
- somepassword=Xj993a== with empty value

The parsing of this would be ambiguous at best.  Now if we escape the '=' characters:

```
somepassword=Xj993a\=\=
```

This is now EXPLICITLY clear as to which is the key and which is the value.

This could also easily have been written as:

```
somepassword:Xj993a\=\=
```

Please read the documentation of [java.util.Properties.load(java.io.Reader)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) for more information on the escapes allowed and parsing semantics of properties files.